QGIS: Display in ECEF Coordinate Systems issues
When the QGIS project coordinate system is set to EPSG:4978 [1] and the OSM WMTS with EPSG:3857 is loaded, the WMTS is not rendered on the canvas.
However, when the project coordinate system is set to EPSG:4326 or any other coordinate system, it displays correctly.
Why is this happening?

[1] EPSG: 4978 is the Earth-Centered Earth-Fixed Coordinate System, abbreviated as ECEF Coordinate System, which is a spatial Cartesian coordinate system commonly used in 3D visualization programs.

Hi, welcome to GIS.SE. Can you edit the question to include a description of EPSG:4978?

EPSG: 4978 is the Earth-Centered Earth-Fixed Coordinate System, abbreviated as ECEF Coordinate System, which is a spatial Cartesian coordinate system commonly used in 3D visualization programs. Why do I need to use QGIS? The reason is that I want to test how QGIS handles when the engineering coordinate system and the actual loaded data coordinate system are different. I have come to the conclusion that it will dynamically convert the data to the engineering coordinate system for drawing.

But I don't understand why the map tiles of OSM (its coordinate system is EPSG: 3857) cannot be drawn when the engineering coordinate system is EPSG: 4978 (it can be drawn when the engineering coordinate system is EPSG: 4326 or other coordinate systems).

QGIS dynamically converts gis data from Layer CRS to Project CRS as you think. However, current and past versions (surely from 3.10 to 3.34) fail to correctly deal with ECEF CRS. I'm experiencing similar issues. A bug has been filed in QGIS github project: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34845
I think it is the same bug which is affecting your tests. In these days I am looking at the source code and it appears that its video render module has been designed to work with 2D or 2.5D CRS (2.5D mean Latitude/Longitude or Northing/Easting + Height and the Height can be somehow ignored when plotting on a 2D display) while ECEF CRS are inherently 3D.
Even though not completely exact, basically QGIS uses the X and Y ECEF coordinates as they were Longitude and Latitude (or Easting/Northing) and ignore the Z.
If you set an ECEF CRS as Project CRS and you use a Layer based on the same ECEF CRS the X and Y are respectively plot on the display columns and rows while the Z is considered as it were the height, so ignored.
I could have been not exact but these are my findings.
